# theres no error but i get "nothing found" for a tag i know there is

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

everytime i try to use the command with a tag that i know for a fact is a tag i get "nothing found"...

im new to coding what am i doing wrong

```
@bot.command()
async def cough(ctx, *, tags: str):
      await ctx.channel.trigger_typing()
      tags = strip_global_mentions(tags, ctx)
      try:
        data = requests.get(
            "https://lolibooru.moe/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit={}&tags={}"
            .format(limit, tags),
            headers=header).json()
      except json.JSONDecodeError:
          await ctx.send("nothing found")
          return

      count = len(data)
      if count == 0:
          await ctx.send("nothing found")
          return
      image_count = 4
      if count < 4:
          image_count = count
      images = []
      for i in range(image_count):
          image = data[random.randint(0, count)]
          images.append("http://lolibooru.moe/images/{}/{}".format(
              image["directory"], image["image"]))
    #await ctx.send("nsfw.results", ctx).format(image_count, count, tags, "\n".join(images))
      await ctx.send(images[0])
```

Comment: I somehow can't access the website you're trying to use. It seems like that `booru.moe` isn't existing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `https://lolibooru.moe/index.php?...` but in the documentation of the API, no one talks about php files. If you want a json response, use `https://lolibooru.moe/index.json?...`

[Lolibooru.moe API Docs](https://lolibooru.moe/help/api)

It is listed under the point **Basics**

Example:
`https://lolibooru.moe/post/index.json?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit=10&tags=azur_lane`

Comment: thank you this did work how ever now i get the error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'directory'`

Comment: @KB256 that means `directory` is not a key in your dictionary. If you have a new question, ask it in a new post and not in the comments of an answer.